reference resolution fail with filecontents
I'm using a journal's template to write my paper. The template uses filecontents for reference. The code looks like below. I found that all my reference code extracted from google scholar(bibtex) can't be displayed correctly(always ends in [?]). However, their example can be displayed. I can't see the difference between my code and their example. I use overleaf. Has anyone encountered this before?
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# article that I want to refer
@article{boyer1975select,
  title={SELECT—a formal system for testing and debugging programs by symbolic execution},
  author={Boyer, Robert S and Elspas, Bernard and Levitt, Karl N},
  journal={ACM SigPlan Notices},
  volume={10},
  number={6},
  pages={234--245},
  year={1975},
  publisher={ACM New York, NY, USA}
}

# Example they give
@Book{arpachiDusseau18:osbook,
  author =       {Arpaci-Dusseau, Remzi H. and Arpaci-Dusseau Andrea C.},
  title =        {Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces},
  publisher =    {Arpaci-Dusseau Books, LLC},
  year =         2015,
  edition =      {1.00},
  note =         {\url{http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/}}
}
\end{filecontents}

The packages I use are
\usepackage{cite}               % order multiple entries in \cite{...}
\usepackage{breakurl}           % break too-long urls in refs
\usepackage{url}                % allow \url in bibtex for clickable links
\usepackage{xcolor}             % color definitions, to be use for...
\usepackage[]{hyperref}         % ...clickable refs within pdf...
\hypersetup{                    % ...like so
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor={green!80!black},
  citecolor={red!70!black},
  urlcolor={blue!70!black}
}


Show the content of the blg file (overleaf does provide that)

there is no need to use filecontents at all here, that;s just a packaging technique to distribute an example as one file. You hav enot shown an example but filecontents won't over-write by default so if you add new entries after the first run, they will not be seen unless you delete the generated .bib file
